# Gmail 2 factor does not work

Tags: pantheon-mail

I cannot setup my Gmail account. It says id or password is wrong. I suspect it is because I have 2 factor authentication setup to text me when I access from a new application or PC. I guess I could turn off 2 factor, but really don't want to do that.

Comment: Just follow rogelin answer, create that app password and use it on the mail app. It will not ask for permission that system was made for this cases

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a one-time app password within your Google account settings and keep using 2fa for all other accesses.
See: https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Comment: Just do this, generate an app password (one-time). You can name it and remove it anytime if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about geary mail, you may need to give permission.

```
Log into your gmail account

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Turn it on. You should get the notification for your 2 factor authentication.
```

Comment: That is not available for 2step verification enabled accounts. In that case you have to create a one-time password or "App Password" (like Google calls it)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Can I delete my reply to not mislead people?

Comment: leave it as a reference